# How do I set timer to making an on off button for 1000 milliseconds?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I am new to c# and I'm wanting to create a game that it has three button with different colors , I want to turn on and off each of them in random state for 1000 milisecond .. what should I do ? can anyone help me ? :)

there are three buttons including Red , Blue and Green colors , after click the "start" button they begin to blink randomly ... I want set 1000 millisecond for this blink !

```
switch (colorNum)
{
    case 1:
        btnRed.BackColor = Color.Red;
        Thread.Sleep(milisecond);
        //if (btn == btnRed)
        //{
            count++;
            break;
        //}
    case 2:
        btnBlue.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        //{
            count++;
            break;
        //}
    case 3:
        btnYellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        //{
            count++;
            break;
        //}
}
```

Comment: Did you search for "timer" in conjunction with your application type (which we don't know)? We can't really help you without knowing more about what kind of app you're building, but it's likely there's a timer which is appropriate...

Comment: don't use thread.sleep for starters, it freezes your GUI thread.

Comment: Given that you want to develop a game, rather than an app, consider using a framework such as MonoGame: http://www.monogame.net/.  This handles the game loop for you

Comment: Given the property name `BackColor`, I'm guessing this is a Winforms program. That said, the question isn't very clear. What does it mean to "turn on and off each of them in random state"? I.e. what is "turn on" and "turn off", and what does "in random state" mean? It would be better if you would provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the context of your question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: yes It is winform program !

Comment: there are three buttons with Red , Blue and Green colors , after click the "start" button they begin to blink randomly ... I want set 1000 millisecond for this blink ... is it clear ???

Comment: You can use System.Threading.Timer to do this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void Blink_Button()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int colorNum = rnd.Next(1, 4);

        switch (colorNum)
        {
            case 1:
                btnRed.BackColor = Color.Red;
                btnBlue.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnYellow.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                break;
            case 2:
                btnBlue.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                btnRed.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnYellow.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                break;
            case 3:
                btnYellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                btnRed.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnBlue.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Call this method in the Timer tick event

Comment: Make the random object global (why?) and set the timer interval to 1000 ms and this should work fine.